# Validation for images with ValidateFileAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-5

I have file, named: ValidateFileAttribute for validation correct input for image uploading. Like this:

```
public class ValidateFileAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
            if (file == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (file.ContentLength > 1 * 1024 * 1024)
            {
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                using (var img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
                {
                    return img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

and this is the propertie of model:

```
[DisplayName("Image")]
    [ValidateFile(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG image smaller than 1MB")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

and this is my view:

```
<div id="upload-choices">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Image)

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-row">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But everytime I try to upload the image(it is png and less then one mb) I get this error:

`var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;` file is null.

Thank you

this is the complete view:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("EditPhotos", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Photos</h4>
                <hr />

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayItem)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayItem)

                </div>

                <div id="upload-choices">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Image)

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-row">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br />

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">

                        <tr>
                            <th><img width="200" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { id =  Model.Id })"></th>


                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <input type="file" name="file" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="Find file">



                <br />
                <div class="progress progress-striped">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">0%</div>
                </div>

                <div id="status"></div>


                <br />

                @*@Html.ActionLink("Upload photos", "Upload")*@
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save"  accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        }

        <br /><br />
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPhotos(UserProfile userprofile, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            ModelState.Clear();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string username = User.Identity.Name;
            // Get the userprofile
            UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

            // Update fields
            user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
            user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", routeValues: new { controller = "Account", activetab = "tabs-2" });
    }
```

and without:  [ValidateFile(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG image smaller than 1MB")] I can upload images. But ofcourse it has to be with validation

I have it now like this:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var ImageProfile = value as byte[];
            if (ImageProfile == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (ImageProfile.ContentLength > 1 * 1024 * 1024)
            {
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                using (var img = Image.FromStream(ImageProfile.InputStream))
                {
                    return img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return false;
        }
```

and propertie:

```
[DisplayName("ImageProfile")]
        [ValidateFile(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG image smaller than 1MB")]
        public byte[] ImageProfile { get; set; }
```

oke, I have it now like this:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var ImageProfile = value as byte[];
            if (ImageProfile == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (ImageProfile.Length > 1 * 1024 * 1024)
            {
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
               using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream))
                {
                    //return img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ImageProfile = binaryReader.ReadBytes(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return false;
        }
```

but ImageProfile is still null?? How can that be?

If I change this:

```
[DisplayName("ImageProfile")]
[ValidateFile(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG image smaller than 1MB")]
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageProfile { get; set; }
```

then this will not work anymore:

```
             user.ImageProfile = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(user.ImageProfile, 0, file.ContentLength);
```

in this method:

```
[HttpPost]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditPhotos(UserProfile userprofile, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"\\Images"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                ModelState.Clear();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string username = User.Identity.Name;
                // Get the userprofile
                UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                // Update fields
                user.ImageProfile = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(user.ImageProfile, 0, file.ContentLength);
                user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    throw;
                }              

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", routeValues: new { controller = "Account", activetab = "tabs-2" });
        }
```

and this:

public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
        {
            var image = db.userProfiles.Where(p => p.Id == id).Select(img => img.ImageProfile).FirstOrDefault();

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream(image.ToArray());

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

But still get an error on this line:  `var stream = new MemoryStream(image.ToArray());`

Comment: Maybe you're not actually uploading the file. I don't see the form element, therefore I can't say if you're doing it right or not. The content type of the form should be `multipart/form-data`. Did you debug your code? Is the `value` in your attribute really `null`?

Comment: The property on your model is a `byte[]`, but your validator is trying to cast value as a `HttpPostedFileBase`, you can't do that the type of value needs to be compatible with the type on your model, ie, change your validator to work with a byte array..

Comment: Your `input[type=file]` is named `file` which is automatically bound to the `file` object in your controller. There is no associated input with your `Image` property.

Comment: yes, but if I try this:  var file = value as byte[]; I cant do this file.ContentLength

Comment: I did the right thing? I correct my class, but ImageProfile is still null?

Comment: Hi Andrei, I updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but ImageProfile is still null?? How can that be?

I can't see an input field in your view with `name="ImageProfile"`. So it's normal that this property is null. So you could start by fixing that:

```
<input type="file" name="ImageProfile" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="Find file">
```

Then you should be aware that the ASP.NET MVC default model binder knows how to translate this file input to an `HttpPostedFileBase` type, not a `byte[]`.

So that would be the next thing you need to fix in your view model:

```
[DisplayName("ImageProfile")]
[ValidateFile(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG image smaller than 1MB")]
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageProfile { get; set; }
```

and obviously reflect this change in your validation attribute:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
    if (file == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (file.ContentLength > 1 * 1024 * 1024)
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
        {
            return img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return false;
}
```

and finally get rid of this file argument in your controller action as it is no longer used:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPhotos(UserProfile userprofile)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin!!  for your answare. see my above edit

Comment: Your controller action should take a view model as parameter, not an actual EntityFramework model. The view model should use HttpPostedFileBase and you would map this to a byte[] in your EF model before passing it to the database